# Java get matches group of Regex

Tags: java, regex

Given following Java expression codes:

```
boolean match = row.matches("('.*')?,('.*')?");
```

if the `match` is `true`, it means the regex matches whole 'row'. Then I could I get the content of the two groups? Each one is `('.*')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the groups you need to use `Matcher`: `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(row)`.

Then you can call `find()` or `matches()` on the matcher to execute the matcher and if they return true you can access the groups via `group(1)` and `group(2)`.

```
String row = "'what','ever'";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("('.*')?,('.*')?").matcher( row );
if( matcher.matches() )
{
  String group1 = matcher.group( 1 );
  String group2 = matcher.group( 2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `String[] groups = row.split(",");`. Then you can use `groups[0]` and `groups[1]` to get each of the 'groups' you're looking for.